# I wish to reload a table view when the user clicks a 'save' button in the navigation view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Basically, I am adding items to a table in a new view and if the user hits save, I want the view to pop off, and the previous table view to update showing the new addition. Any ideas on how to accomplish this task?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PersonTableViewCell"];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"PersonTableViewCell"]autorelease]; 
    }
    p = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[p description]];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try first pop the current view controller by:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Then in your table view controller's `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`, call

```
[self reloadData];
```

to update.

Comment: Problem is, when I do this, it says that I sent the message to a deallocated instance, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: The previous table view controller should not be deallocated. Nor should navigation controller. If they did, you hadn't been managing them correctly in other parts of the code.

Comment: I determined it isn't the table view controller but rather an object 'p' that causes the error:

Comment: Jerome, are you doing that [self reloadData] in the previous table's view controller (which should work, as Shiming suggests), or are you trying to do it from your current view controller that you just popped off (which would, of course, give you the deallocated error).

Comment: See my edit, I added my cellforrow method, the p is causing the problem, when I push the view and then pop and reload, it says that p is deallocated. I am reloading the previous tables for sure. This actually happens on first load though...before I can push or pop the next view when I add reloadData to viewWillLoad, viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear etc.

Comment: This doesn't make sense because when you add something to a NSMutableArray, it's retain count is incremented, so unless you're doing explicit releases it in the code you're not sharing, it doesn't make sense. I'd suggest shift-command-B to "Analyze" your code's use of alloc/init's and your releases. Or if you make the leap to ARC, a lot of these headaches go away.

Comment: VICTORY! I had been instantiating the friendsArray in the numberofrows in section, and apparently that gets deallocated after the first load or something. So I recreated the array in the cellforrow section and it worked. Thanks so much guys!